# Como coletar uma resposta do usuário com Go?

Tags: golang

Olá, estava aqui brincando um pouco com Go e me surgiu uma dúvida, assim como em PHP que existe a função scanf(), em Go temos algo semelhante?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o pacote `fmt` para [fazer o scan](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#hdr-Scanning). Como é possível ver no snippet de código a seguir:

```
fmt.Println("Coloque o seu nome: ")
var nome string
fmt.Scanln(&nome)
fmt.Println(nome)
```

Para mais detalhes pode ler a [documentação dos métodos Scan](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Scan).

Comment: Tem um problema com a pergunta, em PHP não existe a função `scanf()`. Caso o AP tenha se referido a função PHP [`sscanf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.sscanf.php) o mais aproximado seria a função GO [`fmt.Sprintf()`](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Sprintf). Caso o AP tenha se referido a função PHP [`fscanf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fscanf.php) o comportamento mais próximo seria alcançado com o tipo GO [`Scanner`](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio#Scanner) passando um arquivo ou variável GO [`io.Stdin`](https://pkg.go.dev/os#pkg-variables).